# Azure AD authentication : Permission error while fetching access token

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

While doing the authentication using Azure AD, i am getting this error.

`AADSTS90008: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'Application (client) ID'(appname). This happened because application is misconfigured: it must require access to Windows Azure Active Directory by specifying at least 'Sign in and read user profile' permission`.

The API permission configured in my application registered in AD are

[image]

But after this error if check in my application permissions page under user consent tab, i can see three permissions.

[image]

Third one which i have not added to my application 
When checked, the user permission is enabled only for the third one, not the required two . User has given consent while logging in .

the consent screen looks like this:

[image]

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}" feature to do the admin consent for your tenant. The users in your tenant will have the required permissions.

This feature currently appears to have display issues. The cleanest approach should be to create a new Azure AD app and use this button to complete the admin consent.

[image]

Comment: This is a work around solution, right? Why the user consent is not working as expected?

Comment: Not sure about that because this feature has some delays after a recent update. At present, the safest approach is to do admin consent for the required permissions on portal or use Force user consent through a URL request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#force-user-consent-through-a-url-request **at one time**.

Comment: i tried force consent. Even then the permission is not getting set and its throwing the same error. But for some users, the permissions are correctly being set and working correctly.

Comment: @TutuGeorge Have you tried with a new Azure AD app?